# как получить значение button js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть кнопка

```
<Button onClick={this.funk} value={"123"} className="buttonDelete">
```

по нажатию вызывается функция

```
funk = () => {
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("buttonDelete").value);}
```

значение value при срабатывании функции выводит undefined
что в коде не правильно?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("buttonDelete")[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```js
funk = () => {
    console.log(document.querySelector(".buttonDelete").value);
}
```

```html
<button class='buttonDelete' value="123" onclick="funk()">$$$</button>
```

Но можно и проще:

```js
funk = (btn) => {
    console.log(btn.value);
}
```

```html
<button class='buttonDelete' value="123" onclick="funk(this)">$$$</button>
```

А в Вашем варианте

```
document.getElementsByClassName("buttonDelete")
```

возвращается массив, и к нему нужно обратиться по индексу, как Вам уже ответили в комментарии

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("buttonDelete")[ i ].value вот так заработало. Спасибо)